# I'm getting an odd crash on boot after upgrading

Tags: 11.10, boot-failure

Hi I have seen all the other questions on here about not being able to boot after upgrading form 11.04 to 11.10 but all the things suggestion in them (other than a complete reinstall) has not helped.

My Issue does however seem to be a bit different to the other reports.

So when I boot normally and leave the system alone I get to "checking Battery" and the system appears to crash.

I can log in to recovery mode but there no errors in any of them.

This is the odd bit. While booting if I go to tty1 i.e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> while the system is booting then the system boots fine and start x with no issues.

I have been able to do this repeatedly and I have no issue booting but if I don't go to tty1 then it will never boot and always crashes at the checking battery stage.

Any ideas would be very helpful as this is very annoying.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).